# Adding headings within an object

Tags: php, object, laravel

I currently have an array of objects that I am trying to sort in to headings, for example at the moment i have a tabular output like this:

2014-02-01
14:15:00
14:50:00

2014-02-01
14:50:00
15:25:00

2014-02-02
11:20:00
12:30:00

2014-02-02
12:30:00
13:05:00

2014-02-04
17:10:00
17:40:00

2014-02-04
17:45:00
18:20:00

But what I'm looking for is a little something like this:

**1st Febuary**

2014-02-01
14:15:00
14:50:00

2014-02-01
14:50:00
15:25:00

**2nd Febuary**

2014-02-02
11:20:00
12:30:00

2014-02-02
12:30:00
13:05:00

**4th febuary**

2014-02-04
17:10:00
17:40:00

2014-02-04
17:45:00
18:20:00

I'm using laravel to retrieve these objects from the database, and each one within the array looks a little something like this:

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#922 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(228) {
    [0]=>
    object(Lesson)#695 (20) {
      ["attributes":protected]=>
      array(16) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(4) "7312"
        ["date"]=>
        string(10) "2014-02-01"
        ["start_time"]=>
        string(8) "14:15:00"
        ["end_time"]=>
        string(8) "14:50:00"
      }
  }
  [1]=> etc...
```

Does anybody know if it is possible to organise the headings this way? Is this a simple function i'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there's no simple function to do what you want (kind of a group by). Assuming you order by date though (or somehow similar dates are grouped together in the Collection), you can use code like the following:

```
// controller action
public function index()
{
    // get all dates, ordered by date
    $_dates = Date::orderby('date')->get();

    $dates = [];
    $date = new Collection; // not really required, just feels nicer
    $curDate = false;

    foreach ($_dates as $_date) {
        // if we have a new date, store current collection in master array,
        // re-instantiate a blank collection, and set the current date
        if ($_date->date != $curDate) {
            if ($curDate !== false) {
                $dates[$curDate] = $date;
            }
            $date = new Collection;
            $curDate = $_date->date;
        }
        $date->push($_date);
    }

    return View::make('index', compact('dates'));
}

// view
@foreach ($dates as $date => $items)
    <h3>{{{ $date }}}</h3>
    <ul>
        @foreach ($items as $item)
            <li>{{{ $item->date }}} {{{ join(' ', $item->times) }}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Obviously you could extract that group-by logic to a helper function (and make the variable names **much** less confusing!)

Comment: Looking at this, won't this set the first collections key to 0, instead of a date?

Comment: Quite right. I've now fixed the code sample to no longer add the first ever (blank) collection to the main array (in the `false`th index).

Answer (score 0):

Well yes - fetch object from the db,traverse and inject it into view, something like this:

```
@foreach($collection as $object)
    <ul> 
    {{$date}}//or fetch date also
    <li>{{$object[0]["record"]}}</li>
    </ul>
@enforeach

@foreach($collection as $object)
    <ul> 
    {{$date}}//or fetch date also
    <li>{{$object[1]["record"]}}</li>
    </ul>
@enforeach
```

Sorry for beeing generic, but collection and object will be your collection and objects names/index.

Comment: This does not achieve what OP wants as far as I can tell.